# I needed to use the pop() to take out a option in a comboBox (array) that i have created...but was stuck

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

i needed to use the pop() so that it takes out the last element in the array (which is located in a comboBox) but this doesn't work...please help!

p.s. i get no errors and everything else works fine when i run the code and so does the button:

MY CODE:

```
var barColours:Array = new Array();
barColours  = ["red", "green", "blue", "orange", "purple"];

comboBox.dataProvider = new DataProvider(barColours);
comboBox.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onChange);
comboBox.x = 670;
comboBox.y = 55;

minus_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, takeAwayCol);

function takeAwayCol(ev:MouseEvent):void
{
      barColours.pop();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the array doesn't "notify" the list of the change you'll need to reassign the dataProvider.

```
var barColours:Array = new Array();
barColours  = ["red", "green", "blue", "orange", "purple"];

comboBox.dataProvider = new DataProvider(barColours);
comboBox.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onChange);
comboBox.x = 670;
comboBox.y = 55;

minus_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, takeAwayCol);

function takeAwayCol(ev:MouseEvent):void
{
      barColours.pop();
      comboBox.dataProvider = new DataProvider(barColours);
}
```

**EDITED per comment**

```
var barColours:Array = ["red", "green", "blue", "orange", "purple"];
var removedBarColours:Array = new Array();

comboBox.dataProvider = new DataProvider(barColours);
comboBox.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onChange);
comboBox.x = 670;
comboBox.y = 55;

minus_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, takeAwayCol);

function takeAwayCol(ev:MouseEvent):void
{
//if you need to pull from the beginning of the list instead of the end use shift/unshift method(s) of Array
      removedBarColours.push(barColours.pop());
      comboBox.dataProvider = new DataProvider(barColours);
} 

function addCol(ev:MouseEvent):void
{
      barColours.push(removedBarColours.pop());
      comboBox.dataProvider = new DataProvider(barColours);
}
```

Comment: sorry, also is there a way to click another button to add those elements that have been taken off back to the end of the array?

Comment: No problem, yeah you'd have to keep another array with the removed values so you just shift them from one list to another, I'll update the code above soon.